# In Rails 4 using AJAX, how do I update a particular div on success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a bunch of images and when I upload another using AJAX, I need to refresh the div that the images are held in. In Rails 3.2 I used to be able to use a partial and render_to_string in the controller and send JSON back with the new html, but that method does not seem to work in Rails 4.

I have a partial called images.html.haml that needs a local variable 'user'

I have a controller that uses the following:

```
respond_to do |format|
  html = render_to_string('_images.html.haml', locals => {'user' => user}) 
  format.json {render :json => {:html => html} }
end
```

However, when I use this method, not only the partial, but the partial within the application layout gets rendered. I did some searching to find that there is now a `:partial` key, so I tried that but then Rails couldn't find the partial. Is there a better way to do this that is supported by Rails 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
html = render_to_string(partial: 'images', locals: {user: user})
```

Comment: Nice! Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this and let me know if it works?

```
render_to_string(:partial => '_images.html.haml', :locals => {'user' => user}, :layout => false)
```

Comment: I get this response: ```ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing partial profile/_images.html.haml, application/_images.html.haml with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in:
  * ".../app/views"
):```

Comment: can you tell the exact path of the file "_images.html.haml" (i.e. directory structure)